# Registration wont input values in database

Tags: php, registration

The values wont insert into my database, the message tells me that registration is complete but nothing gets stored in database, please help. Thanks!

> Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections;
>   please explain your scenario more clearly.

Heres code:

```
$submit = $_POST['submit'];

$name = strip_tags($_POST['fullnamefield']);
$regemail = strip_tags($_POST['regemailfield']);
$password = strip_tags($_POST['regpasswordfield']);
$repeatpassword = strip_tags($_POST['regpasswordconfirmfield']);
$date = date("Y-m-d");

if ($submit)
{

    if ($name&&$regemail&&$password&&$repeatpassword)
    {

        if ($password==$repeatpassword)
        {

        if (strlen($name)>32||strlen($regemail)>1024)
        {
         echo "Length of name or email is too long.";
        }
        else
        {
        if (strlen($password)>32||strlen($password)<6)
        {
        echo "Password must be between 6 and 32 characters long.";
        }
        else
        {

        $password = md5($password);
        $repeatpassword = md5($repeatpassword);

        $connect = mysql_connect("xx","xx","xx");
        mysql_select_db("xx");

        $queryreg = mysql_query("

        INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','$name','$regemail','$password','$date')

        ");

        die("You have been registered!");

        }

        }
        }
        else
            echo "Your passwords do not match";
    }
    else
        echo "Please fill in all fields.";

}
```

Comment: You're showing `You have been registered` using `die()`, which is for failures. Why are you doing that? "If registration fails, show the message it worked" makes no sense at all.

Comment: I was following tutorial, it said to say that

Comment: Actually, reading the code again, you're saying "Do this insert, then cause a fatal error that says things worked", which probably causes the insert to fail. Remove (comment out) the `die` line and see what happens, and then go back to your tutorial and make sure you're actually following it. I think you made a mistake.

Comment: I commented out the die line, still nothing is happening.
Tutorial is this:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W1zaEiZawsI&feature=fvwrel

Comment: As I said, check your tutorial again. I think you lost your way, or made major mistakes in the code. Sorry, I don't have the time (or desire) to follow the video tutorial to see where your mistake might be;  you'll have to do that yourself. (Also learn to indent your code properly, so you can see where opening and closing braces (`{` and `}`) line up, to make sure blocks are closed in the proper places.)

Comment: The error is most likely in your SQL query. The first value you pass in is an empty string. What is the first column in your table `users`?

Comment: id, its recurring so tutorial said not to put anything, either way wouldn't it just skip that value and insert the rest where they're supposed to go?. . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get some diagnostic information, I'd add

```
or die(mysql_error());
```

to your mysql_query statement making the final line

```
$queryreg = mysql_query("

    INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','$name','$regemail','$password','$date')

    ") or die (mysql_error());
```

What this will do is output any errors mysql is having during the query.  Post them back here if you aren't sure what you're looking at.

Hope this helps.